# What is the scope of the study of Neuroanatomy?

Tags: neuroanatomy

I am now trying to understand the scope of the study of neuroanatomy as the [discussion in meta](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2533/7604) surrounding the question [Dorsum sellae, tuberculum sellae and sella turcica which of the 3 is referred to by the adjective sellar?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26185/7604) has raised the question on whether the [Neurocranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurocranium) would be studied by [Neuroanatomy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroanatomy)?

If you apply that logic, in my view 90% - 100% of human anatomy could be under the umbrella of neuroanatomy.

[Dermatomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatome_(anatomy)) relate to the anatomy of the vertebral regions of the spine. The nerves travel throughout the body, the organs and within the skin.

In my view, neuroanatomy covers the structure and organization of the nervous system which in turn involves the brain, spinal cord and related neural networks throughout the body.

Am I wrong and the whole body (or close to it) is under the umbrella of neuroanatomy?

Answer (score 1):

It is the traditional division of anatomy by systems. Neuroanatomy is simply another name for anatomy of the nervous system - both macroscopic and microscopic. As opposed to anatomy of skeleton and muscles, internal organs and topographical anatomy. And of course one remembers the division of macroscopic anatomy and microscopic (which further goes into cytology and histology). So in summary -- yes, the whole body - but just as far as the nerve cells and structures are involved. And please remember - an extremely precise definition here will defy the reason because a lot of these words and divisions are traditional - therefore to be viewed with their own history of use, which may change with time.

Source: Dorland’s Illustrated Medical Dictionary, Sobotta Atlas of Anatomy and Anatomy Textbook. It also helps if one has attended medical school.